# WARNING ITMS-90737: "Invalid Document Configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I got this error message when uploading my app to ItunesConnect today,

> Invalid Document Configuration - Document Based Apps should support
>   either the Document Browser (UISupportsDocumentBrowser = YES) or
>   implement Open In Place (LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = YES/NO).
>   Visit https://developer.apple.com/document-based-apps/ for more
>   information.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate, but the other question does not have an accepted answer and this one does.  The accepted answer to this question helped me resolve my issue quickly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To Fix -

Open `Info.plist` file.

**If** you have `UIDocumentInteractionController` within your App use -
Add "UISupportsDocumentBrowser" select boolean YES

**Otherwise -**
Add "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" select boolean YES

`Info.plist` **Code:**

```
//if using - UIDocumentInteractionController
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
    <true/>

//if not use - 
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

**From the Apple Developer Documentation**

```
UISupportsDocumentBrowser
```

UISupportsDocumentBrowser (Boolean - iOS) Specifies that the app is a document-based app and uses the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class.

If this key is set to YES, the user can set the document browser’s default save location in Settings. Additionally, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in the app’s Documents directory. These documents appear in the Files app, and in a Document Browser. Users can open and edit these document in place.

This key is supported in iOS 11 and later.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController
```

Use this class to present an appropriate user interface for previewing, opening, copying, or printing a specified file. For example, an email program might use this class to allow the user to preview attachments and open them in other apps.
After presenting its user interface, a document interaction controller handles all interactions needed to support file preview and menu display.
You can also use the delegate to participate in interactions occurring within the presented interface. For example, the delegate is notified when a file is about to be handed off to another application for opening. For a complete description of the methods you can implement in your delegate, see UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate.

[Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

```
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace
```

LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace (Boolean - iOS) When set to a value of YES, enables your app to open the original document from a file provider, rather than a copy of the document. The app can access documents from the system’s local file provider, the iCloud file provider, and any third-party File Provider extensions that support opening documents in place.

The URL for a document opened in place is security-scoped. For information about working with security-scoped URLs and bookmarks, read the overview in NSURL Class Reference and read Document Provider in App Extension Programming Guide.

Important: When opening a document in place, other processes can modify the document at any time. Therefore, you must coordinate your access to the document using either a UIDocument subclass or NSFilePresenter and NSFileCoordinator objects.
In iOS 11 and later, if both this key and the UIFileSharingEnabled key are YES, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in the app’s Documents directory. These documents appear in the Files app, and in a document browser. Users can open and edit these document in place.

[Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW13)

**Setting Up a Document Browser App** [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/setting_up_a_document_browser_app)

Comment: Please read the error message. You set one or the other, not both, depending on the needs of the app.

Comment: Don't set `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` to true if your app doesn't! If you're just wanting to get your app working as before with no changes then setting this to false may be correct.